# C++ object creation and constructor

Tags: c++, object, constructor

I'm learning ctors now and have a few question. At these lines:

```
Foo obj(args);

Foo obj2;
obj2 = Foo(args);

Foo obj3 = Foo(args);
```

**First part**: only 1 constructor called (Foo) and `obj` is initialized. So, 1 object creation.

**Second part**: creating of temporary object `obj2`, calling default ctor for it. Next lines we create another copy of `Foo` and pass its copy into `operator=()`. Is that right? So, 3 local  temporary objects, 2 constructor callings.

**Third part**: create 1 object `Foo` and pass its copy into `operator=()`. So, 2 temprorary objects and 1 ctor calling.

Do I understand this right? And if it's true, will compiler (last gcc, for example) optimize these in common cases?

Comment: `operator=()` usually receives its argument by reference, so no copies in calling it.

Comment: obj3 is actually created using copy constructor not assignement operator.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I will comment on the third one first:

```
Foo obj3=Foo(args);
```

It doesn't use `operator=` which is called copy-assignment. Instead it invokes copy-constructor (theoretically). There is no assignment here. So theoretically, there is two objects creation, one is temporary and other is `obj3`. The compiler might optimize the code, eliding the temporary object creation completely.

Now, the second one:

```
Foo obj2;         //one object creation
obj = Foo(args);  //a temporary object creation on the RHS
```

Here the first line creates an object, calling the default constructor. Then it calls `operator=` passing the temporary object created out of the expression `Foo(args)`. So there is two objects only the `operator=` takes the argument by `const` reference (which is what it should do).

And regarding the first one, you're right.

Comment: Okay, thanks. But anyway, in first case only 1 objects of type `Foo` is created, in third one: 2 objects?

Comment: No, according to the specs, part 1 and part 3 are two ways of specifying the same thing. There is no difference in implementation.

Comment: @MrLister: No. There is a subtle difference between `1` and `3`. Just write a test code, and make the copy-constructor `private`. The 1st one will compile, the third one will not!

Comment: Aw. I'm sure I was taught this when I learned C++. But you're right that it won't compile. And I can't find references to it being synonyms for the same thing. So, thanks and sorry. And I'm gonna ask my money back.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, `Foo obj(args)` creates one Foo object and calls the ctor once.
2. `obj2` is not considered a temporary object. But just like 1 `Foo obj2` creates one object and calls the `Foo` ctor. Assuming that you meant `obj2 = Foo(args)` for the next line, this line creates one temporary Foo object and then calls `obj2.operator=()`. So for this second example there is only a single temporary object, a single non-temporary, Foo ctors are called twice (once for the non-temporary, once for the temporary) and the operator=() is called once.
3. No, this line does not call `operator=()`. When you initialize `obj3` using the `=` syntax it is almost exactly as if you had used parentheses instead: `Foo obj3(Foo(args));` So this line creates a temporary object, and then calls the Foo copy ctor to initialize obj3 using that temporary object.

Answer (score 2):

Your terminology is a bit confusing.

The objects `obj`, `obj2` `obj3` are not called "temporary objects". Only the instance that is created in line 3 before being assign to obj is a temporary object.

Also, you don't create "a copy of Foo", you create either "an instance of Foo" or "an object of type Foo".