# How does `Foo obj = Foo(1)` work

Tags: c++, constructor

Referring to the thread here: [C++ object creation and constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777240/c-object-creation-and-constructor), the sentence `Foo obj = Foo(1);` should involve two object creations: one invoking `Foo(int)`, the other `Foo(const Foo&)`, namely copy-ctor.

```
class Foo{
    Foo(const Foo&){ //print "Foo(const Foo&) called" }
    Foo(int i){//print "Foo(int) called" }
    ...
}

...
Foo obj = Foo(1);
```

The above code only prints "Foo(int) called". How does it work in this case? Since I add printing functions in the ctors, it shouldn't be optimized out by the compiler, right?

Comment: see about [Copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision)

Comment: There is special permission to elide copies, even if it changes observable behaviour.

Comment: @jsantander thanks for the pointers. This term "copy elision" is new to me.